# ffmpeg not running - libaom.so.0 not found

Tags: ffmpeg

`ffmpeg` is not running in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

```
$ ffmpeg -version
ffmpeg: error while loading shared libraries: libaom.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Ubuntu version

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
```

System information:

```
$ uname -a
Linux r2d2 5.15.0-48-generic #54-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 26 13:26:29 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I've tried to reinstall `ffmpeg` and its dependencies and the error is still the same.

```
$ apt-cache depends ffmpeg | grep '[ |]Depends: [^<]' | cut -d: -f2  | tr -d ' ' | xargs sudo apt-get --reinstall install -y
$ sudo apt reinstall ffmpeg
```

Any tips on how to solve it?

Comment: Find a file in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` that starts with `libaom.so`. There is probably only one. It could be e.g. `libaom.so.3.3.0`. Then create a symbolic link: `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libaom.so[...full filename]  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libaom.so.0`. Now the file `libaom.so.0` can be found by `ffmpeg`.

Comment: @Jos after doing that a similar problem happened for ```libfdk-aac.so```, ```libx264.so``` and ```libx265.so```. I installed the packages ```libfdk-aac-dev```, ```libx264-dev``` and ```libx265-dev``` and created links as you proposed. Now the error is: ```ffmpeg: symbol lookup error: ffmpeg: undefined symbol: x264_encoder_open_160```

Comment: At this point, you may as well reinstall `ffmpeg`: `sudo apt install --reinstall ffmpeg`.

Comment: @Jos, I've done that... still the same error.

Comment: `whereis ffmpeg` please.

Comment: ```$ whereis ffmpeg```

```ffmpeg: /usr/bin/ffmpeg /usr/share/ffmpeg /home/leoca/bin/ffmpeg /usr/share/man/man1/ffmpeg.1.gz
```

oh... I don't know why... but there is one in my home folder... removing it solves the issue